# new iOS start to ignore meta viewport maximum-scale for device-width

Tags: html, ios, css, viewport, meta

I noticed, that the "classical scenario" with meta `viewport` for a fixed `device-width` along with `maximum-scale=1` doesn't prevent the page from zoom-in by user on the [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) anymore.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

A bit more input on where already did tests:

- I had tests on `iOS 10.3.2`, `11.0.1`, and very latest `11.0.3` - behavior is the same, property of viewport is ignored.
- I noticed that Facebook on mobile in iOS Safari also allows you to zoom in, this haven't been possible before, as the page is responsive;
- Android device with `v.4.4.2` with native browser and Chrome 60.0.3112.107, still work with this instruction well, zoom-in is not allowed more than device-width.

I haven't found any information in relation to it on [apple's developers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) and it seems iOS started to pretty much ignore [`maximum-scale` properties from W3C CSS Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#min-scale-max-scale).

Does anyone know how to **prevent zoom-in** on the pages, maintaining `maximum-scale=1` for the `device-width` for the pages/apps designed to be responsive? Any data on when it changed, and starting from what [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) version? How do you solve it from now (if possible at all)? Thanks.